# Schedulling a task to run silently

Tags: windows-10, task, uac

I have scheduled a task to run multiple times a day which calls a .reg file.

Whilst it runs without any problem, I have to accept two warnings before it executes each time.

Is there any way to have it execute without warning prompts?

It is set to run with highest privileges and hidden.

The OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

In the task scheduler, instead of just running the entry **file.reg**,
I put the entry ***reg import file.reg***.

This is run at highest privileges and it runs silently.

Answer (score 0):

Open the properties of the Executable file 
In the General tab check the Unblock checkbox

Comment: Thanks Debabrata,

The .reg file is called directly by the task and there is no unlock option in the properties of the .reg file.

Answer (score 0):

@Debabrata, I'm shamelessly 'borrowing' an image from another forum in order to clarify that...

...Only files that come from a different source machine (including those found online) will show the 'Unblock' option, and only then if the file has also been flagged, and subsequently blocked.

Files that have been created locally wouldn't have this flag as the file is from, well, the very same machine.

For the avoidance of doubt, it would be nicer to have the unblock option always shown and simply be greyed-out, in lieu of the flag being set. That would almost certainly clear things up for many, but not something that I think is necessary, and therefore likely wouldn't be developed by M$.

Anyway, here's the image to show what you would ordinarily be looking for, in order to unblock a Registry file (.reg).

[A screenshot of the 'General' tab of a Registry file's Properties dialogue, detailing how to unblock a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3e8q.png)